# Calling a nested function present inside JQuery declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function called "destination" nested in scrip1.js file. If I add this file at the end of webpage using , how can I trigger it at the next step? Here are some contents of script1.js.

script1.js

```
$.something = function(element, options) {
  function start() {
    function destination(arg1, arg2..) {
       $.notify(some args);
    }
  }
  $("body").on("click", ".notify-btn", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      destination(some args);
  });

  someOtherFunction();

  start();
}

$.fn.something = function (options) {
  return this.each(function () {
    if (undefined == $(this).data("something")) {
      var plugin = new $.something(this, options);
      $(this).data("something", plugin);
    }
  });
};
```

I tried this, but is not working. Chrome console is showing error about this function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script>
$.fn.something().destination();
</script>
```

I can not change this script1.js, so any possible way?

Comment: what returns `$.fn.something()` (try to log it)?

Comment: I tried console logging. It is showing JQuery object

Comment: That's not how you call  a  `$.fn` function either. Should be `$(selector).something()`

Comment: Does `$.something` return anything in your real code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific connection between variables declared during function execution - and how the rest of the world sees the result of execution. So this code:

```
function start() {
  function destination(arg1, arg2..) {
     $.notify(some args);
  }
}
start();
```

... lets `destination` value (remember, functions in JS are first-class citizens) go away when `start()` completes its execution. That's actually quite convenient if you want to encapsulate some implementation details and hide it from users; this technique (also known as [Module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)) was often used in pre-class world to implement private properties in vanilla JavaScript.

However, all the values *returned* from a function can be reused. For example, here...

```
$.something = function(element, options) {
  function start() {
    function destination(arg1, arg2..) {
       $.notify(some args);
    }
    return {
      destination 
    };
  }
  return start();
}
```

... you make `destination` function a part of object that is returned from `start()`. Now `$.something` returns an object, too; that means it can be reused:

```
  var plugin = new $.something(this, options);
  // ... 
  plugin.destination('some', 'args');
```

---

If you're afraid changing the return value might hurt someone, you can try to assign value of `destination` to `$.something` object itself as its property, like this:

```
$.something = function(element, options) {
  function start() {
    function destination(arg1, arg2..) {
       $.notify(some args);
    }
    return destination;
  }  
  // ...
  const destination = start();
  $.something.destination = destination;
}
```

The returned value is not modified, yet function is accessible. Still, that's not actually a good workaround; the biggest issue is that any subsequent calls on `$.something` will rewrite the value of that function, which might be not a good thing if its execution depends on some scoped variables.

---

While technically there's a way to fetch `destination` function code by parsing `$.something` source code, I really doubt it's worth the effort in your case.

Comment: So is there no other way to call `destination` without changing the contents of script1.js?

Comment: Essentially yes. Technically, you can parse the function body and recreate it within your script - but that's a long and tricky road not really worth it. Why exactly you cannot change the contents of script1.js?

Comment: It is a custom framework. Afraid that it will ruin other logics. I assume returning `destination` might stop execution of following functions. I edited my question to be more precise.

Comment: Being afraid of breaking something that barely works is not a good way to do software engineering. I'm not sure about the framework you use, but the code you've shown is meaningless: `$.something` doesn't return anything, yet somehow is assigned to `plugin`. Unless you add some meaningful details to the question, it'll be hard to help you here.